# Generate app and library in single webpack build

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm building a library that can be used as a dependency in another webpack build (e.g. `import Foo from 'foo'`) -or- used directly within the browser via a global variable (e.g. `new window.Foo()`).

For the first case, I'm used to specifying library values for the webpack build (e.g. `library`, `libraryTarget`, etc); however, when I do this, the global variable use case doesn't work b/c the code that attaches `Foo` to the window doesn't run unless you first import the module somewhere.

If I remove the `library*` fields from the webpack config, I can get the global to work, but the `import Foo from 'foo'` case no longer works.

Is it possible to generate a lib + app bundle from a single webpack config? Or do I need to literally generate two bundles, one for the lib and one for the app?

Comment: Try `libraryTarget: 'umd'` and `library: 'name'` in your webpack config.output. Obviously replace "name" with your library name.

Comment: @Sidney that doesn't seem to work. In that configuration, the `import Foo from 'foo'` works, but the global var never gets set on the window object. I think it's b/c the lib bundle isn't executed without first importing it.

Comment: Hm, I'm pretty sure UMD should do it. How are you exporting the library from the entry file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue.

When you set `library` to a name (e.g. `Foo`) in webpack, it will place a reference to the built module in that global variable (e.g. `window.Foo`).

This seems all well and good, but since I was using ES6 modules, the actual result was that what I wanted to be in `Foo` was really `Foo.default` due to the ES6 module structure. That wouldn't be intuitive at all for consumers of the library.

What I ended up doing was changing the webpack library name to `FooModule` and then in my code, I manually set `window.Foo` to the code I actually wanted my end-developers to be able to use if they weren't also using a webpack build.